# Spring Boot Security Ldap Rest Controller

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-ldap, spring-restcontroller

I am currently implementing RestControllers with Spring Security Ldap.

The login is successful and the user informations are well returned.

The problem is coming when the front end in angular wants to call my Rest api, the security returns unauthorised status. (should not as I am supposed to be logged in)

I am new in spring security so maybe I am missing something simple in my configuration :)

Here is some screenshots and configuration code sample (I erased some datas from the screenshots for confidential purposes) :

[GetDocuments Unauthorized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeW6M.png)

[GetDocuments unauthorised Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqUzz.png)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("com.*")
@PropertySource(value= {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class LdapSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private HttpAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private HttpLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() throws Exception {

        LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(getBindAuthenticator());
        ldapAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(new UserDetailsContextMapperImpl());


        return ldapAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

                http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(authorizeRequestsCurrentUser).permitAll()
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().rememberMe()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .permitAll()
                    .loginProcessingUrl(loginProcessingUrl)
                    .usernameParameter(userNameParameter)
                    .passwordParameter(userPasswordParameter)
                    .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
                .and()
                    .logout().permitAll()
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(logoutRequestMatcher, RequestMethod.GET.name()))
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                    .logoutSuccessUrl(logoutSuccessUrl)
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .maximumSessions(1);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            auth.eraseCredentials(false).authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()).ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter(ldapUserSearchFilter)
                .groupSearchBase(ldapGroupSearchBase)
                .userDetailsContextMapper(new UserDetailsContextMapperImpl())
                .contextSource(getLdapContextSource());
    }

    private BindAuthenticator getBindAuthenticator()throws Exception{
        LdapContextSource contextSource = getLdapContextSource();

        String searchFilter=ldapSearchfilter;
        FilterBasedLdapUserSearch userSearch=new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch(ldapSearchBase, searchFilter,contextSource);
        userSearch.setSearchSubtree(true);


        BindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        bindAuthenticator.setUserSearch(userSearch);
        bindAuthenticator.afterPropertiesSet();

        return bindAuthenticator;
    }

    private LdapContextSource getLdapContextSource() throws Exception {
        LdapContextSource cs = new LdapContextSource();
        cs.setUrl(ldapUrl);
        cs.setBase(ldapBase);
        cs.setUserDn(ldapUserDn);
        cs.setPassword(ldapPassword);
        cs.setPooled(true);
        cs.afterPropertiesSet();
        return cs;
    }

}



@Component
@Log4j
public class AuthSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    AuthSuccessHandler(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter) {
        this.mapper = messageConverter.getObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        LdapUser authUser = (LdapUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        MyUser user = new MyUser();
        user.setUsername(authUser.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(cred);

        // set our response to OK status
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE+"; charset=UTF-8");

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        mapper.writeValue(writer, authUser);
        writer.flush();
    }
}




public class CORSFilter  implements Filter{
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS,"true");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE, "3600");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {}
}



@Component
public class UserDetailsContextMapperImpl extends LdapUserDetailsMapper {

    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username,
                                          Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        UserDetails userDetails= super.mapUserFromContext(ctx,username,authorities);
        String fullName = ctx.getStringAttribute("givenName");
        String email = ctx.getStringAttribute("mail");
        return new LdapUser((LdapUserDetails)userDetails,fullName,email);
    }
}


@Log4j
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@ComponentScan("com.*")
@RequestMapping(value = "${config.rest.uri.entry.path}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class DashboardController {

    @Autowired
    IDashboardService dashboardService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "${config.rest.uri.dashboard.documents}",method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Result<List<DashboardDocument>> getDocumentList(@RequestParam(value="username") String username){


     ----------------

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

had you resolve your problem since 2 years ? :-p

I want to do the same thing and i'm interested to your code, should you share it ?

Otherwise, i have a way, add this to your onAuthenticationSuccess (found here : https://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security ):

```
    SavedRequest savedRequest
      = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

    if (savedRequest == null) {
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        return;
    }
    String targetUrlParam = getTargetUrlParameter();
    if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl()
      || (targetUrlParam != null
      && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParam)))) {
        requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        return;
    }

    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your rest api to know that user is authenticated, the request has to contain authentication information. Usually it would be in the request headers. [This](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) spring tutorial shows how to use Angular in order for authentication info to be passed. Notice, that this only supports Basic authentication.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have investigated more and when I look at the spring security debug logs, I have the feeling the Security context is not saved but I dont know why. I will post the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the spring security logs :

[spring security logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnNSR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already found the answer, but just for the sake of the completeness, here is the one line code that causes your restcontrollers requests access denied. in your configuration, you are using `.formLogin()` as a way to transfer the credential to your restcontrollers, but rest controllers are sessionless, it doesn't take any thing from your session. You will need a different way to transfer your credential from your client to the rest controller. One way is to change `.formLogin()` to `httpBasic()`.